# Visual Studio 2010 - Multiple Projects building the same source

Tags: visual-studio

I've seen this done before, but I was wondering how to set it up in VS2010.

Basically, I am working on a library that I want to build on the Windows Phone framework as well as the Windows x86/x64.

I will be coding it inside a Windows Class Library and wanted to be able to compile and make sure the same source works inside Windows Phone.

Is there any way to do this?  I know I can add an existing file "Linking" the file, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.  I really want 2 project files in the same source folder, just 1 is for Windows and the other for Windows Phone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I did this, I created links to the existing files.  In the 2nd (mobile) project I defined a special symbol that affected the compile of all the various modules.

you said you didn't want to do this, not sure why.

Comment: I don't mind doing it, just seen it done differently before.  Also, what symbol did you define?  Adding the project already targets it to SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE.